# Prevent to create Spring batch meta-data table inside mysql DB

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch, application.properties

I am using spring Batch 3.0.7. Is is possible to prevent the creation of meta data table in DB.

In my application by default bellow org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql file code is exacting by Spring Batch.

How I can prevent to execute this file so it will not create the meta data table inside production DB.

If without creation of meta data table is not possible, then how I can point to different 2 DB so, I will create the meta data table in Local DB so inside production DB any meta data table will Not create.

how we can configure in Application.properties file for 2 Different DB .

1. one for create the meta data creatiopn DB.
2. another is production DB where I can fetch the record.

   20:37:21.898  INFO 8280 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql]
   2018-03-06 20:37:25.987  INFO 8280 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql] in 4089 ms.
   2018-03-06 20:37:26.138  INFO 8280 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
   2018-03-06 20:37:26.138  INFO 8280 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: MYSQL
   2018-03-06 20:37:26.546  INFO 8280 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
   2018-03-06 20:37:26.693  INFO 8280 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=job]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]

Comment: Which version of  Spring Boot are you using? Have you [looked at the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-spring-batch-database)?

Comment: Hi Stephane I added this spring.batch.initialize-schema=never in my Application.properties file but still its creating the meta data table in my DB and I am using Spring Boot 1.4.1

Comment: You should read the doc for the version you're using. `never` only works in 2.0